# Create a new column with the text of another column between parentheses

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns

I am new to Power BI and I am trying to create a new table column based on the values of an actual column in the table, between parentheses.

Actual column = Frankfurt (FRA)
New Column = FRA

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerQuery, select your actual column, then go to `Add Column` tab in the ribbon, and select `Extract > Text Between Delimiters`. The add `(` for start and `)` for end.

[image]